# AJAX calls of JSF 2 now return a <redirect> in JSF 2.2. Managed Beans are not getting executed

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

We are migrating from JSF 2 to JSF 2.2. 
Ideally, there shouldn't be a problem on the f:ajax tags.

But, to trigger calls on load of the page.

The code base uses empty anchor links which are then triggered via a click in jQuery.

```
<h:commandLink id="lnkTriggerTitleAndPFGuidance" tabindex="-1">
            <f:ajax execute="#{RecoEx}" render="#{RecoRen}" onevent="oDesc.XXX" listener="#{recoCommand.populate (core, pricing)}" />
        </h:commandLink>
```

The above link's click is triggered via jQuery.

```
$(function(){$('#lnkTriggerTitleAndPFGuidance').click()});
```

The form field ID's, which are mentioned in the *execute* , are present in the POST tab, of the NET tab of Firebug. But the corresponding Managed Bean is not hit if debugged.

The Rendered response is :

```
<partial-response><redirect url="home.jsf"></redirect></partial-response>
```

Besides, this, there are no errors in the console of the app on Eclipse. Its really hard to find out what the issue is.

Finally, the call shows a 200 OK.

Immediately there is a pop-up,

> The page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you
>   may entered may not be saved - Stay on Page / Leave Page

If clicked on 'Leave Page', it re-directs the page mentioned in the response.
There are no exceptions occurring in the back end to really find what the issue is.

Any help

Comment: That onbeforeunload dialog is not part of standard JSF. Given the fact that you explicitly mentioned it anyway, may we assume that the given code snippet is not a MCVE at all? Namely, I don't immediately recognize the described problem as one of standard JSF behaviors.

Comment: Might be a security filter in place that behaves differently now. Is migrating the jsf version the only thing you do?